# Meta Question: Asked in Math Stack Exchange, Unanswered: Can I move it Here?

Tags: discussion

My apologies in advance if this is off-topic; I searched to see if this question was acceptable here, but could not find a clear answer. Anyways: I posted a question on Math Stack exchange two weks ago, on some issues re Lefschetz Pencils (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593611/trying-to-understand-lefschetz-pencils), and no one has answered it. May I post it in here, or should I wait a bit longer? Best tag I found was "ref. request". Feel free to delete this after answering.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you for asking about migration — many people post on MO after waiting mere hours for an answer on MSE.  And do note that your meta question has migrated to its appropriate home: meta.mathoverflow.

I won't be able to answer your linked question, as it's not in my area.  But from what I can tell it looks like it would be very appropriate on MathOverflow.

I do recommend that when you post your question here, you spend a little time cleaning it up.  You can certainly incorporate your edits in order to make the version here clearer, with fewer seams.  I also strongly recommend that you change a few internet short-hands ("tho", "thru", "AFAIK") into more standard academic English: we try to maintain a quasi-professional environment, and that includes style of writing.  (I don't mean in any way to suggest that "tho", for example, is somehow "wrong": it is both part of common vocabulary and unambiguous.  I only mean that it is a style that doesn't read as well in this venue.)

Comment: Thanks, Theo, will do so soon, and will try to be clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on the answer that Theo gave, note that technically speaking you can ask for the math.SE moderators to migrate your question over to MathOverflow, thus eliminating duplicate efforts.

That been said, I suggest that shortly before, or immediately after you incorporate the edits suggested by Theo.